# How Symfony isolate SESSION values of application?

Tags: php, session, symfony

I try to understand how Symfony isolate SESSION values of application. 
I create two files:

```
// test.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['aaa'] = 111;
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

and

```
// test2.php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

So when I call `http://localhost/test.php` and then call `http://localhost/test2.php`, I get same SESSION in both files:

```
array(1) { ["aaa"]=> int(111) }
```

But when I add to the end of symfony front controller `app_dev.php` next code:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

and try to call  `http://localhost/app_dev.php` - I get only Symfony session

```
array(3) { ["_sf2_attributes"]=> &array(0) { } ["_sf2_flashes"]=> &array(0) { } ["_sf2_meta"]=> &array(3) { ["u"]=> int(1396360435) ["c"]=> int(1396360433) ["l"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

and I don't get access to the `array(1) { ["aaa"]=> int(111) }` value, that I expected.

Why? And how can i do mutual session values with this 3 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony use `NativeFileSessionHandler` as default, and all data in this storage will be not expected in another systems.

As solution, you can create native session handler as service (Class already exists in Symfony/HttpFoundation package) and set this handler to configuration `framework.session.handler_id`

For more information, you can see in [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks for advice! What about `NativeFileSessionHandler`? Can I simply use it in another system for not to create own handler?

Comment: Yes. The `NativeFileSessionHandler` in Symfony can write session to file, and implement of SessionHandlerInterface (In PHP Core).

Comment: And I necessarily need to use Symfony Session component for it? Can I unserialize session without this component, using only `SessionHandlerInterface` and native PHP?